# Groovy initialization of array of objects containing array property

Tags: arrays, groovy, initialization

I have the following code:

```
class User {
    String id = ""
}

class Customer {
    String id = ""
    User[] users
}

Customer[] customers = new Customer[5]

for (i=0;i<numCustomers;i++) {
    customers[i] = new Customer()
    customers[i].id = "customer:" + (1000+i)
    customers[i].users = new User[3]
    for (j=0; j<users.size(); j++) {
         customers[i].users[j] = new User()
         customers[i].users[j].id = customers[i].id 
    }
}
```

The initialization of the customers array seems correct. If I only have the "id" field it works fine. However, when I added the "users" field, with the code showed above I get "No such property: users" on the line:

```
customers[i].users = new User[3]
```

Why is this? Also, I am new to Groovy, so please point out any other issue with my code above.

Comment: in `for (j=0; j<users.size(); j++)` what is the `users` ? I guess you meant `customers[i].users` ...

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I overlooked it, also because the editor I'm using at the moment is not pointing out where the error is. Thought for sure it was on the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for (j=0; j<users.size(); j++) {
```

is the line causing trouble. No `users` variable is defined in the class running your script. Judging from you code, you probably wanted to use

```
 for (j=0; j<customers[i].users.size(); j++) {
```

For the future, I suggest using an IDE, IntelliJ has a really nice Groovy support.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you're creating `customers[i].users = new User[3]` but testing users.size() in loop when assigning users to the custumer.

Assuming numCustomers = 5 try something like the folowing:

```
for (i=0; i < numCustomers; i++) {
    Customer customer = new Customer()
    customers[i] = customer
    customer.id = "customer:" + (1000+i)
    customer.users = new User[3]
    for (j=0; j < 3; j++) {
         User user = new User()
         user.id = customer.id
         customer.users[j] = user
    }
}
```

If you wanted to replace array of users with a List then it could look like this:

```
class Customer {
    String id = ""
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>()
}

for (i=0; i < numCustomers; i++) {
  // ...
  for (j=0; j < 3; j++) {
    User user = new User()
    user.id = customer.id
    customer.users.add(user)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Customer[] customers = (1000..1005).collect { id ->
    new Customer( id:"$id", users:(1..3).collect {
        new User( id:"$id" )
    } )
}
```

Not tried it, but I think it's OK